# How can I turn off Front-End editing of articles without changing Content Permissions?

Tags: com-content, global-configuration

Our component depends on the users permission to edit articles, but is intended to intervene with that editing process, so the icon that *allows* the article editing to occur is a problem for us.

GLobal configuration allows setting some options,etc., but I've been unable to actually stop the icon from being there as long as the permissions allow editing.

Can the feature be turned off without needing a template override of some kind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [Content Plugin](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_content_plugin) can accomplish this.  To prevent F/E editing for articles this works:

```
public function onContentBeforeDisplay($context, &$article, $params, $page=0) {
    if( $context == 'com_content.article' ) {
        $article->params->set('access-edit',0);
    }
}
```